# How to use Razor variable as model property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a method that returns one of several properties as a string. I would like to use the result of that method as a property of the page model. I cannot figure out the syntax though.

```
string modelProp = item.Type.ToTaskRequirementJobDescriptionSummary();

<ul>
    @foreach (var summary in Model. + modelProp)
    {
        <li>@Html.Raw(@summary)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

That doesn't work, and neither does `@foreach (var summary in Model.(modelProp))`.

How can I use the result of the method to access the relevant property of the model?

Comment: You probably need to use Reflection to get the properties, loop through them and check each one with your `modelProp` and use that. I personally prefer to not make a mess on my views.

Comment: This could very well be an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/163532). Essentially, you're asking about how to make a particular solution to your problem that you've decided on work, instead of the actual problem itself. If you give more information about what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to come up with a better way. If you are going to use reflection, I would recommend creating an HtmlHelper extension or similar, so you can at least keep the reflection code out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write function as an action and then call from razor using render action method

```
@{Html.RenderAction(summary);}
```